# Texture loading with DevIL, equivalent code to texture loading with Qt?

Tags: opengl, glsl, devil

I am working with opengl and glsl, in visual studio c++ 2010. I am writing shaders and I need
to load a texture. I am reading code from a book and in there they load textures with Qt, but I
need to do it with DevIl, can someone please write the equivalent code for texture loading with DevIL? I am new to DevIL and I don't know how to translate this.

```
// Load texture file
const char * texName = "texture/brick1.jpg";
QImage timg = QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat(QImage(texName,"JPG"));

// Copy file to OpenGL
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
GLuint tid;
glGenTextures(1, &tid);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tid);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, timg.width(), timg.height(), 0,
             GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, timg.bits());
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that DevIL is no longer maintained, and the ILUT part assumes the requirement for power-of-2 texture dimensions and does rescale the images in its convenience functions, it actually makes sense to take the detour of doing it manually.

First loading a image from a file with DevIL happens quite similar to loading a texture from an image in OpenGL. First you create a DevIL image name and bind it

```
GLuint loadImageToTexture(char const * const thefilename)
{

    ILuint imageID;
    ilGenImages(1, &imageID);
    ilBindImage(imageID);
```

now you can load an image from a file

```
ilLoadImage(thefilename);
```

check that the image does offer data, if not so, clean up

```
void data = ilGetData();
if(!data) {
    ilBindImage(0);
    ilDeleteImages(1, &imageID);
    return 0;
}
```

retrieve the important parameters

```
int const width  = ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_WIDTH);
int const height = ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_HEIGHT);
int const type   = ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_TYPE); // matches OpenGL
int const format = ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_FORMAT); // matches OpenGL
```

Generate a texture name

```
GLuint textureID;
glGenTextures(1, &textureID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
```

next we set the pixel store paremeters (your original code missed that crucial step)

```
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SWAP_BYTES, GL_FALSE);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, 0); // rows are tightly packed
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, 0);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS, 0);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1); // pixels are tightly packed
```

finally we can upload the texture image and return the ID

```
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, format, width, height, 0, format, type, data);
```

next, for convenience we set the minification filter to GL_LINEAR, so that we don't have to supply mipmap levels.

```
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

finally return the textureID

```
    return textureID;
}
```

If you want to use mipmapping you can use the OpenGL `glGenerateMipmap` later on; use glTexParameter GL_TEXTURE_MIN_LOD and GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LOD to control the span of the image pyramid generated.